# logging: how to lock the whole logging engine for one thread?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have mulithreaded application that uses logging.

Sometimes I would like to log a couple of lines in a row with one logger and be sure that other thread does not insert its lines between.
So I need a lock, probably on the whole logging engine.

Is it feasible?

Comment: Why not just put a lock around the lines that you want to log together?  The lock prevents other threads from getting in at the point.

Comment: I don't want any thread to log anything at any part of the code - not just only within the same block.

Comment: There must be some logic in your program to end that condition.  Release your lock at that point.